# Python: using HMAC signing to use API (implementation from PHP example)

Tags: php, python, api, hmac, bitcoin

I have little trouble when i try to use bitcoin exchange API via python. 
I have example function in PHP:

```
function bitmarket_api($method, $params = array())
{
$key = "my_key";
$secret = "my_secret";
$params["method"] = $method;
$params["tonce"] = time();
$post = http_build_query($params, "", "&");
$sign = hash_hmac("sha512", $post, $secret);
$headers = array(
"API-Key: " . $key,
"API-Hash: " . $sign,
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.bitmarket.pl/api2/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$ret = curl_exec($curl);
return json_decode($ret);
}
```

And it is my python implementation:

```
def bitmarket_api(method, params):

    key = 'my_key'
    secret = 'my_secret'
    url = 'https://www.bitmarket.pl/api2/'

    params['method'] = method
    params['tonce'] = timestamp()

    post = urllib.urlencode(params)
    sign = base64.b64encode(str(HMAC(secret, post, sha512).digest()))

    headers = {}

    headers['API-Key:'] = key
    headers['API-Hash:'] = sign

    req = urllib2.Request(url, post, headers)
    res = urllib2.urlopen(req, post)
    return json.load(res)
```

So, when i try to to invoke info method (or other method) i get 'Invalid API key' error.
I was looking for solution, and i was trying several other approach with no succes.
Can u guys help me? I think problem can be in headers...
Please excuse my poor English. I try to do my best, but I'm still making mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python HMAC Auth lib with Requests lib
https://github.com/bazaarvoice/python-hmac-auth

Nice and tidy to let your build your client without too much trouble.